# A wow video to teach Calculus

Tags: online-instruction, online, videos

I am teaching Calculus (one and also several variables). I would like to create questions in which students would watch a short video and then answer a question related to the content of the video. In this way, students might find it interesting and appreciate the subject. The video is not necessarily related to Maths (directly), but at some point in the video we could ask a simple question related to Calculus, such as limits or derivatives.

I would think that there are only a very few such videos on the internet. Nevertheless, could you recommend me a video?

Thks.

Comment: "watch a short video and then answer a question related to the content of the video"

Do you mean you'll demonstrate something and then viewers will work a similar problem?

Comment: I mean that I would like to find a video on the internet that  I can create a Math question from it.

Comment: @Nick C Wow, wow. Your recommendation is outstanding. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan Meyer used to do "[Three-Act Math Tasks](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1jXSt_CoDzyDFeJimZxnhgwOVsWkTQEsfqouLWNNC6Z4/pub?output=html)" where he would start with a short video (followed by math questions, etc). Maybe you can re-purpose these videos for a calculus audience.

Answer (score 1):

For Calc II, there is [a great scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhdBDWZVXks) from the movie Holes. A slightly shorter shovel is preferred, because you can dig a slightly smaller hole. How much smaller? (The movie is great.)

Comment: As I recall, related rates is something studied in Calc I.  Love the movie idea.

Comment: I used it with volume of rotation and surface area, I guess. But you are right, it would also go well with related rates. (The question that comes most naturally from the movie is not a related rate. It is 'How much work is saved with the shorter shovel, or how much less dirt is dug?')

Comment: @nick_c, thank you for the clip! (I had no idea it was available on youtube. I have a clipped copy on my computer. And I believe Dan Meyer helped me with that.)